# What kind of health insurance does a foreigner need when applying for German student visa from Paris?

Tags: germany, indian-citizens, health-insurance, health

I wish to apply for a German student visa to start my doctoral studies. I'm an Indian national and currently residing in Paris.

One needed document for visa application is health insurance proof. I'm not quite sure if my French public health insurance would work fine or I have to buy another health insurance just for 3 months. After starting my doctoral studies, I will get health insurance from my research institute. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Your French health insurance is sufficient. You should request the EU travel insurance (a blue card). You will have to switch to a German insurance within 3 to 6 month.

The German system is slightly different than in France, you have different companies managing your health insurance (e.g. tk.de or aok.de). They will provide you the same coverage with small differences like add-ons (e.g. yearly cancer skin screening). Depending on your salary, the health insurance will be automatically deducted from your salary or you will have to "pay it yourself" (usually less than 100€). Ask the institution that is hiring.

Please note that health insurance is mandatory in Germany.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!! I will submit my french health insurance as a proof of health insurance for visa application.